# how to use one command argument for both Get and Set?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to implement argument parsing by using argparse. What I need is to have one option for both Get and Set command. Is this possible in Python?

The is what I need - for example:

```
$ python prog.py -width
Width is 15 cm.
$ python prog.py -width=20
Width is set to 20 cm.
```

I tried. But I couldn't find a way to implement it. I have to use 2 different names for the option. One is "getwidth", another is "width". Here is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("-width", help="Set width")
parser.add_argument("-getwidth", action='store_true', help="Get width")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.width:
    print("Set width to %s cm" % args.width)
if args.getwidth:
    print("Width is %s cm" % width_value)
```

Here is the result of my code:

```
$ python ts.py -getwidth
Width is 21.0 cm
$ python ts.py -width=25
Set width to 25 cm
```

Comment: This is not possible with `argparse` as far as I can tell. You can make an argument not require values using `action='store_true'` like you did, but you cannot make two arguments with the same name, or it raises `argparse.ArgumentError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `nargs='?'`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument(
    "-width",
    help="Set width",
    nargs='?',
    const='get',
)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.width == 'get':
    print("Width is %s cm" % 1)
elif args.width is not None:
    print("Set width to %s cm" % args.width)
```

[You can read about the `nargs` argument here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Comment: Thanks luther! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @user1556331: Using `nargs='?'` is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it so that an arg value of 0 gets converted to the default value. Like this ...

```
import  argparse

width_value = 5

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("-width",  help="Set width (0 = use default)")

args = parser.parse_args()
action = ""

if args.width != "0":
    width_value = int(args.width)
    action = "set to "

print("Width is %s%s cm" % (action, width_value))
```

Giving the output ...

```
$ python pyargs.py -width=11
Width is set to 11 cm

$ python pyargs.py -width=0
Width is 5 cm
```

Comment: Thanks jcfollower. I thought about this as well. It's probably a solution.